# iText PDF: запись HTML в PDF в кодировке UTF-8

Tags: java, pdf, itext

Задача: из переданного `HTML` создать что-то наподобие печати (в заданных координатах) внутри существующего `PDF`-документа.
Я нашел два варианта перекидывания `HTML` в `PDF`. 
Первый метод `createPdfUtf8()` поддерживает `UTF-8`, но нет возможности задать координаты. Второй метод `createPdf()` без возможности задать кодировку, но позволяет играть с координатами.
Нет ли возможности задать первому методу координаты или же второму кодировку? Спасибо.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    String html_S = "<b style=\"font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; line-height: normal; color: rgb(0, 47, 255);text-align:center;\">ЗАО &#171;ПК &#171;Рога и Копыта&#187;</b>"
            + "<b style=\"font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; line-height: normal; color: rgb(0, 47, 255);text-align:center;\"><br /> Сертифицирован</b>"
            + "<b style=\"font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; line-height: normal; color: rgb(0, 47, 255);text-align:right;\"><br /> Сх. № <u>ПР-RR-00011-18</u></b>"
            + "<b style=\"font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; line-height: normal; color: rgb(0, 47, 255);text-align:center;\"><br /> от <u>10.04.2018</u></b>";

    createPdfUtf8("C:\\1.pdf", html_S);

}
public static void createPdfUtf8(String file, String html_S) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(file));
    document.open();

    XMLWorkerHelper worker = XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance();
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(html_S.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    worker.parseXHtml(writer, document, is, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    document.close();

}

public static void createPdf(String file, String html_S) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(file));
    document.open();

    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
    table.addCell("Some rich text:");
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
    for (Element e : XMLWorkerHelper.parseToElementList(html_S, null)) {
        cell.addElement(e);
    }
    table.addCell(cell);
    document.add(table);
    document.close();
}
```

Первый метод отрабатывает сейчас так:
[image: Печать]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Первый вариант не позволяет вам работать с "координатами" так как он парсит *html* страницу и конвертирует её в *pdf*. Второй же позволяет вам работать с таблицами и не как не с "координатами". А теперь к решению.

Вынесите весь ваш html в отдельный файл и там уже форматируйте страницу как вам удобно. После чего конвертируйте её в pdf. Вот пример:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        b {
            font-family: Arial,serif;
            font-size: 10pt;
            font-style: normal;
            font-variant: normal;
            font-weight: normal;
            line-height: normal;
            color: rgb(0, 47, 255);
        }
        .right {
            text-align:right;
        }
        .center {
            text-align:center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="right">
        <b class="center">ЗАО &#171;ПК &#171;Рога и Копыта&#187;</b>
        <b class="center"><br /> Сертифицирован</b>
        <b class="right"><br /> Сх. № <u>ПР-RR-00011-18</u></b>
        <b class="center"><br /> от <u style="">10.04.2018</u></b>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Сам метод создания *pdf* файла ничем не отличается, лишь тем что *html content* читается из файла.

```
public static void createPdfUtf8(String file) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(file));
    document.open();

    XMLWorkerHelper worker = XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance();
    InputStream is = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("file.html");
    worker.parseXHtml(writer, document, is, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    document.close();
}
```

Результат
[image: Результат]